# Update single <td> value in the table row using ajax in django

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to Block/Unblock the user without refreshing the page. If the status=1, it will show Block option, and if the status=0 it will show Unblock option

After calling the function, the status will change either 0 or 1 in views.py
The function is working fine but it is showing after refreshing the page

How to display that  value without refreshing the page

```
<table id='usersTable' class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Block/Unblock</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for userid, name, email, status in comb_lis %}
    <tr id='usr-{{name}}'>
        <input type="hidden" id="{{userid}}" name="{{userid}}" value="{{userid}}">
        <input type="hidden" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{name}}">
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{email}}</td>
        <td> <a href="#" onclick="restrictUser(document.getElementById('{{userid}}').value, document.getElementById('{{name}}').value)">
            {% if status == "1" %}
                Block
            {% else %}
                Unblock
            {% endif %}
        </a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

and this is the ajax function

```
function restrictUser(userid, name) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/restrict-user-ajax/'+userid,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status) {
            alert("User Blocked!");
        }
    }
});
```

}

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `restrictUser` function you can pass `this` as well which will refer to the current element which is clicked and use `.text()` to get the current text inside `a` tag .Then , under success function of ajax check if `data.status` is true depending on this change the text of particular `a` tag either `block` or `unblock`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = {
  "status": true
} //demo json

function restrictUser(userid, name, el) {
  var els = $.trim($(el).text()); //trim any whitespace
  console.log(els)
  /*$.ajax({
    url: '/restrict-user-ajax/' + userid,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {*/
  //check if status is true
  if (data.status) {
    //check previous text was block/unblock
    if (els == "Block") {
      //change text
      $(el).text("Unblock")
    } else {
      $(el).text("Block")
    }
  }
  /*}
  });*/


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='usersTable' class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Block/Unblock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id='usr-{{name}}'>
      <input type="hidden" id="{{userid}}" name="{{userid}}" value="{{userid}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{name}}">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>s@gmail.com</td>
      <!--add this to function as paremter-->
      <td> <a href="#" onclick="restrictUser(document.getElementById('{{userid}}').value, document.getElementById('{{name}}').value,this)">Unblock</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='usr-{{name}}'>
      <input type="hidden" id="{{userid}}" name="{{userid}}" value="{{userid}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{name}}">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>something2</td>
      <td>y@gmailc.com</td>
      <td> <a href="#" onclick="restrictUser(document.getElementById('{{userid}}').value, document.getElementById('{{name}}').value ,this)"> Block </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='usr-{{name}}'>
      <input type="hidden" id="{{userid}}" name="{{userid}}" value="{{userid}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{name}}">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>sss</td>
      <td>g@gmail.cm</td>
      <td> <a href="#" onclick="restrictUser(document.getElementById('{{userid}}').value, document.getElementById('{{name}}').value,this)">Unblock
        </a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working like a charm. Thank you for the help